# How to catch a value from a chain of piped functions?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I have this chain of functions

```
%{key1: "value 1", key2: "value 2"}
|> CustomModule.func1
|> CustomModule.func2
|> CustomModule.func3
```

How can I assign the return value to a variable like `final_result` to then use it in a case statement or test it further?

Comment: It's good to bear in mind that as in most functional languages, everything in Elixir is an expression.  That means that code of the general form "map |> op |> op |> op" is an expression which returns a value.  Hence as @gazler pointed out, you just need to bind the value of the expression to a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just bind using `=`

```
final_result = %{key1: "value 1", key2: "value 2"}
|> CustomModule.func1
|> CustomModule.func2
|> CustomModule.func3
```

Some people prefer the following style (https://github.com/niftyn8/elixir_style_guide#source-code-layout):

```
final_result =
  %{key1: "value 1", key2: "value 2"}
  |> CustomModule.func1
  |> CustomModule.func2
  |> CustomModule.func3
```

Comment: Perfect. I was stuck trying to attach it to the end. This is a bit mind-bending if you're new to functional programming...

Comment: You can also pipe straight into a case statement `true |> case do: (true -> "hello")` however I will leave it up to you to decide if you think it is more readable.

Comment: I found piping into a `case` really useful when the computed value needs to still be destructured, for example `func3` returns `{:ok, result}` and you just want the `result`